# What are the rendering differences between FF2 and FF3?

Tags: firefox, firefox-3

I've noticed slight spacing differences in HTML rendering between these versions in Windows XP.

Is the box-model interpreted in a slight different manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might as well check it at http://www.quirksmode.org/

Answer (score 1):

Found this: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Websites_look_wrong

It's not specifically about FF3, but can help.

Answer (score 0):

The differences you noticed are the differences you’re looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Sometimes I feel like it, sorry. :)